# How to Test APIs in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am new to Unit Testing. I have tested a lot of functions and I understood the concept, now I want to check the APIs. Is it possible? I guess so. This is the API:

```
func sendRequest(path: String, params: Dictionary<String, Any>, showSpinner: Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON, Error?) -> Void) {
    if Constants.IS_SIMULATOR {
        print("Path: \(path)")
        print("Params: \(params)")
    }

    if Constants.APP_DEL.reachability?.connection == .none {
        completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: "No internet", code: 4, userInfo: nil))
        return
    }

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    if showSpinner {
        HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: "Loading...", subtitle: "Please wait"))
    }

    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) {

        let url = NSURL(string: String(format: "%@%@", Constants.TEST_URL, path))!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.timeoutInterval = 120

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if error != nil {
                    print(" ........ \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

                    if showSpinner {
                        HUD.flash(.labeledError(title: "Server issue", subtitle: "Invalid response"), delay: 2.0)
                    }

                    completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: "Invalid response", code: 420, userInfo: nil))
                    return
                }


                if (data?.isGzipped)! {
                    let decompressedData: Data = try! data!.gunzipped()
                    var json: JSON = JSON.null
                    do {
                        json = try JSON(data: decompressedData)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    if Constants.IS_SIMULATOR {
                        print("Response: \(json)")
                    }

                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false


                    if json["status"].int == 200 {
                        if showSpinner {
                            HUD.flash(.success, delay: 0.5)
                        }
                        completionHandler(json["data"], nil)
                    }
                    else if json["status"].int == 202 {
                        if showSpinner {
                            HUD.hide()
                        }
                        completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: json["message"].string!, code: json["status"].int!, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                    else if json["status"].int == 310 {
                        if showSpinner {
                            HUD.hide()
                        }
                        completionHandler(json["data"], nil)
                    }
                    else if json["status"].int == 403 {
                        if showSpinner {
                            HUD.hide()
                        }

                        GeneralHelper.sharedInstance.displayAlertMessage(titleStr: "Session expired", messageStr: "Kindly login again.")

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {

                            let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
                            UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
                            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                            Constants.APP_DEL.navC?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                        })
                        completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: json["message"].string!, code: json["status"].int!, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                    else {
                        if showSpinner {
                            HUD.flash(.labeledError(title: "", subtitle: json["message"].string!), delay: 2.0)
                        }
                        completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: json["message"].string!, code: json["status"].int!, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let backToString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
                    if Constants.IS_SIMULATOR {
                        print("Invalid response: \(String(describing: backToString))")
                    }
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false


                    if showSpinner {
                        HUD.flash(.labeledError(title: "Server issue", subtitle: "Invalid response"), delay: 2.0)
                    }
                    completionHandler(JSON.null, NSError(domain: "Invalid response", code: 420, userInfo: nil))
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

So, to test this I have done this:

```
func testAPIWorking() {
    params = ["ios_token": "dq6YJkKwEx0:APA91bFeOTfJRFd5G78xMkv3AvjSLA7ey2dJxTZZAtMuuC50CqWILNzNjdgqVpNpDn7R4I0DLoydIVDYKubpGfgfu1bwz1H3VNU4D88ek8PJTAjxrd3CWkW78g0sNv6EZDLlTqUFeNxh", "api_token": "kfRSHL0bVP1fSmxNY3NfEGs8g0ktKCbTsPRRbfarh3a5ISIcZLu3qdK07MJ9H4rJ", "player_id": 8083]

    ServiceHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(path: "home", params: self.params, showSpinner: false) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            XCTFail("Fail")
        }
        else {

        }       
    }
}
```

I have added a breakpoint at task and it prints the task but then when I try to move to next line, instead of going into `Dispatch` it takes me out of that and stops at `task.resume()` and because of this I am not able to test the `errors` or expected `results`. Any help?

Comment: Jeez, please format your code. This isn't C.

Comment: You cannot unit test this. If you want to test this, you need an *integration test*. You can unit test only small, independent units of code, not something that depends on the state of a server, your internet connection etc. Extract parts of your implementation into separate function (e.g. parsing), *then* you can unit test these parts.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/709-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial may it helpes you

Comment: Are you sending API requests via Burp or Charles?  Both have free versions and let you inspect your app's request and modify the response to check your error handling is good.

Answer (score 5):

Here you have a completion handler, the api call in not sync. So you should to wait the result in your test. In Xcode you could use `XCTestExpectation`.

For example:

```
    func testAPIWorking()
        {

            let expectation = XCTestExpectation.init(description: "Your expectation")
            params = ["ios_token": "dq6YJkKwEx0:APA91bFeOTfJRFd5G78xMkv3AvjSLA7ey2dJxTZZAtMuuC50CqWILNzNjdgqVpNpDn7R4I0DLoydIVDYKubpGfgfu1bwz1H3VNU4D88ek8PJTAjxrd3CWkW78g0sNv6EZDLlTqUFeNxh", "api_token": "kfRSHL0bVP1fSmxNY3NfEGs8g0ktKCbTsPRRbfarh3a5ISIcZLu3qdK07MJ9H4rJ", "player_id": 8083]

            ServiceHelper.sharedInstance.sendRequest(path: "home", params: self.params, showSpinner: false) { (result, error) in

                if error != nil
                {
                    XCTFail("Fail")
                }
                // The request is finished, so our expectation
                expectation.fulfill()
            }
            // We ask the unit test to wait our expectation to finish.
            self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 20)
        }
```

Comment: Throws an error `Ambiguous reference to member 'expectation(description:)'`

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to initialise the expectation. Check the new answer version.

Comment: Yeah, I got that I added the expectation, but still don't know if it is working or not.

Comment: Are you using a specific Library for testing ? Have you correctly set you testing target in your Xcode project (it should be different a target than your app)

Comment: Ok, I got everything working now, but what should I expect like if the status code returns 200?

Comment: It depends on your request. What your request is supposed to respond ?

Comment: It is supposed to return an `arrayObject`. I am new to Unit Testing, do you think it is good idea to Test APIs?

Comment: Actually when I want to test an api returning a jsonObject I test if I can correctly parse it. For example here you can check your Json's message.